# How do I add a custom attribute to the `<form>` element generated by the Contact Form 7 WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to do it **without javascript**.

For example, the form HTML rendered on the page normally looks like this:

```
<form action="/contact-us/#wpcf7-f713-p61-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form submitting" novalidate="novalidate" data-status="submitting">
```

But I need to add the custom attribue `data-netlify="true"` so the form should end up like this:

```
<form action="/contact-us/#wpcf7-f713-p61-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form submitting" novalidate="novalidate" data-status="submitting" data-netlify="true">
```

There is a [similar question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274317/how-to-add-a-custom-attribute). But that is for putting a custom attribute on the input, I need the custom attribute on the form itself.

Comment: If you browse the source code `contact-form.php`  line 500 - you'll see that there are no filters to add additional attributes to the `<form>` tag, and anything passed to the existing filters that could possibly do this are sanitized, like the `autocomplete` filter. It would seem that javascript might be your only route here.

Answer (score 0):

If the action always is the same on the form you could use javascript to add it

```
<script>
  var data = document.querySelector('[action="/contact-us/#wpcf7-f713-p61-o1"]');
  data.setAttribute('data-netlify', true);
  console.log(data);
</script>
```